# Is there a way only include @Test data in results in reportportal

Tags: reportportal

Is there a way only include `@Test` data in results, In my case I use **testng** but in results I get `@beforeSuite`, `@BeforeMethod`, `@BeforeClass` all these included in results as a test. I want to include only `@Test` data.

Answer (score 1):

Actually we dont need to have that feature, because if we dont want to see specific annotations in results then UI supports filter on these annotations.

Comment: it's right. You can hide those methods from representation on UI. But we have to report them, since it contains pre-steps for test cases you have.